# Magento2 custom Knockout binding

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am working on a customization of the checkout page in M2, in particular I am trying to add to the 'discount' section of the page. In this part of the page I need to call a third party javascript library *once the html template has loaded*.

I have looked into [knockout lifecycle events](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-lifecycle-events.html), however they are unavailable, because they are 3.5.0, and KO version in M 2.3.1 is 3.4.2.

Now I am looking into adding [a custom binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), and hoping to add the call to the third party lib in the `init` method.

My code looks roughly like this:

/app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/discount.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/action/set-coupon-code',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/action/cancel-coupon',
    'certificateInfo',
    "setCertificateInfo",
    "cancelCertificateInfo",
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/model/payment/discount-messages',
], function ($, ko, Component, quote, setCouponCodeAction, cancelCouponAction, certificateInfo, setCertificateInfo, cancelCertificateInfo,errorProcessor, messageContainer) {

    ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
            // Call third party lib here
        }
    }
});
```

/app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html

```
<p data-bind="myBinding: blah">
  <!-- Markup that needs to have 3rd party call to work... -->
</p>
```

All that is happening is an error on the page

`[ERROR] Failed to load the "Company_Module/js/view/payment/discount" component.`

Any idea what I am doing wrong with custom binding, or a different way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think custom Knockout bindings for Magento is Your answer.

Usage example:

```
<div afterRender="function (target, viewModel) {
    console.log('Rendered element:', target);
    console.log('Associated view model:', viewModel);
    console.log(this === viewModel);
}"></div>
```

Source:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html

Useful links:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/How-to-call-function-after-rendering-a-knockout-js-template/m-p/58781#M925

Comment: YES!!!!! I spent over 2 hours messing with that - thank you sir!